# Increasing google datastore quota for load testing?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I hit this error when I started load testing my REST API deployed on a GAE app spot URL.

**The API call datastore_v3.RunQuery() required more quota than is available.**

Any help on which particular setting to change on cloud console would be appreciated. I have enabled billing on the account. But need to upgrade the quota for datastore reads.

Thanks
Srik

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the GAE (Google App Engine) [spending limit](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/#setting_a_spending_limit) to a larger number. This is due to the Datastore currently being integrated into App Engine and therefore shares its spending limit.